# How to Check 2 lists for similar items?

Tags: c#, list, linq, foreach

I have 2 lists (**myItems** and **anotherItems**), I want to see if the items on the myItems are on the anotherItems?

I am currently using 2 foreach loops But speed is very slow and takes about 1 minute to do.

myItems = `IEnumerable<SomeModel>`

anotherItems = `IEnumerable<String>`

```
foreach (var item in myItems)
{
    foreach (var subItem in anotherItems)
    {
        var parsed = ParseItem(subItem, item.Id);
        if (parsed.Id != null && parsed.version != null)
        {
            if (item.Id.Equals(parsed.Id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                myList.Add(new myModel
                {
                    Name = item.Name,
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Version = parsed.version
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and PareItem is:

```
public static (string Id, string version) ParseItem(string line, string Id)
{
    line = Regex.Replace(line, "[ ]{2,}", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    line = Regex.Replace(line, $@".*(?=({Regex.Escape(Id)}))", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var lines = line.Split(" ");
    if (lines.Count() == 2)
    {
        return (Id: lines[0], version: lines[1]);
    }
    return (Id: null, version: null);
}
```

How can I do this faster?

Comment: Can you make some assumptions about your input data? Are they for example sorted?

Comment: Huge amount of unnecessary string manipulation there. Use capturing groups or even simple IndexOf. Show your input data

Comment: Also, you reparse the same items N times, where N is the number of items on the outer list- that's a complete waste of time. Parse the inner list to a Hashset once using anything that looks like an Id and traverse the outer list asking if the set contains the item

Comment: Most often, identifying the best data representation then selecting the correct algorithm will give a bigger performance boost than optimizing the code we already see. Following on from that, `parsed.Id` and `parsed.version` are currently string identifiers. Are they meant to be strings or are they numeric values represented as strings? Can the `parsed.Id` pattern be "abc123" or is it always something like "123"? Similarly for `version`.

Comment: @DanielDearlove you can see it in image in my question

Comment: @user16267434 I see the code blocks but no image. My question was about the contents of the data you are parsing. If you can parse the `Id` and/or the `version` properties to integers then comparing integers is far faster and easier than comparing strings. Must you compare strings or can you parse the input to other basic types?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following solution as your problem is that your are doing the extraction of the same items for each of the iterations of `myItems`:

1. Do a full parsing of the `anotherItems = IEnumerable<String>` into a `IEnumerable<SomeModel>` even if only some of the properties can be set (we know Id can be set in any case).
2. You can then use the [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0)

```
public class SomeModel: IEquatable<SomeModel>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(SomeModel other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        return this.Id.Equals(other.Id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as SomeModel);
    public override int GetHashCode() => (id).GetHashCode();
}
```

So I'd expect your code to look like:

```
// In this line iterate all items from the second list and extract.
myAnotherItemsList = ExtractSomeModelFromAnotherList(anotherItems);
var mergedList = myList.Intersect(myAnotherItemsList);
```

Comment: The problem is that first I have to parse the items with ParseItem method and for this I need item Id.

Comment: If no further assumptions can be made, removing the matched line from the original list might speed things up a little. Otherwise you'd need to find some way to extract the ids. Would it be possible to get all numbers from the string and assume the id is one of them? That would also give solutions.

Comment: @user16267434 we're effectively limited to what you're capable of imagining in terms of offering solutions here, because you haven't posted a sufficient representation of the actual problem; you've posted your solution and said "help, it's slow, how to make it faster" but we know nothing of the data you are working on because you haven't posted it. As such it's an XY problem, and we can only extract/infer up to the limit of what you were capable of.

Comment: If instead you post the actual problem ("I have a list of objects like X this.. and a list of strings like this.. how can I get the intersect?") then we can offer solutions up to the limit of what WE are capable of, which is actually what you're looking for...